# Implementing 2 independent swiper.js sliders on one page - how do I implement a delay in one of them?

Tags: javascript, animation, slider, swiper.js

I have implemented two independent swiper.js sliders in a webpage, and would like them both to autoplay independently. I have set an animation delay on one of the sliders which works until the 4th slide (on the first slider), and 5th slide on the second which happen simultaneously. Is there any way to ensure one slider plays followed by the next slider for every slide? I have tried setting animation delays on both swipers to different settings and the same problem occurs in different degrees.

code below:

```
var swiper1 = new Swiper('.swiper1', {
            slidesPerView : 1,
            autoplay: true,
            loop: true,
            speed: 1000,
            arrows: false,
            watchSlidesVisibility: true,
            spaceBetween : 0,
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination-11',
                type: 'bullets',
                clickable: true
            },
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.ht-swiper-button-next-4',
                prevEl: '.ht-swiper-button-prev-4'
            },
            // Responsive breakpoints
            breakpoints: {
                1499:{
                    slidesPerView : 1
                },

                991:{
                    slidesPerView : 1
                },

                767:{
                    slidesPerView : 1

                },

                575:{
                    slidesPerView : 1,
                    spaceBetween : 0
                }
            }
        });
        
        var swiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper2', {
            slidesPerView : 1,
            loop: true,
            autoplay: {
                delay: 2000,
            },
            speed: 1000,
            arrows: false,
            watchSlidesVisibility: true,
            spaceBetween : 0,
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination-2',
                type: 'bullets',
                clickable: true
            },
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.ht-swiper-button-next-4',
                prevEl: '.ht-swiper-button-prev-4'
            },
            // Responsive breakpoints
            breakpoints: {
                1499:{
                    slidesPerView : 1
                },

                991:{
                    slidesPerView : 1
                },

                767:{
                    slidesPerView : 1

                },

                575:{
                    slidesPerView : 1,
                    spaceBetween : 0
                }
            }
        });
```

and html

```
<div class="industry-slider-area section-space--inner--120">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Engineers Topics</h3>
                        <div class="industry-two-slider">
                            <div class="swiper-container swiper1 industry-two-slider__container">
                                <div class="swiper-wrapper industry-two-slider__wrapper">
                                    {% for item in engineers_topics %}
                                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                                            <div class="industry-two-slider__single-item">
                                                <div class="industry-two-slider__single-item__image">
                                                    <a href="{{ item.link }}">
                                                        <img src="{{ placeholder|resize(470,300) }}" data-src="{{ Image(item.thumbnail).src|resize(470,300) }}" class="img-fluid" alt="{{ item.title }}">
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="industry-two-slider__single-item__content">
                                                    <h3 class="title">
                                                        <a href="{{ item.link }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
                                                    </h3>
                                                    <p class="subtitle">{{ item.preview.read_more('')|truncate(25) }}</p>
                                                    <a href="{{ item.link }}" class="see-more-link see-more-link--dark">SEE MORE <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">
                                 <div class="swiper-pagination-11 swiper-pagination-11"></div>
                                <button class="slider-button"><a href="https://www.jps-machinery.co.uk/engineers-topics/">Read More Engineers Topics </a></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="newsletter-box-wrapper bg-img" data-bg="{{ 'message.png'|media }}">
                            <h3 class="newsletter-title">Request a Callback</h3>
                            <div class="newsletter-form-wrapper">
                                {{ function('do_shortcode', '[wpforms id="12290"]') }}
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="call-text">or Call Us: {{ options.phone_number }}</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Customer Case Studies</h3>
                        <div class="industry-two-slider">
                            <div class="swiper-container swiper2 industry-two-slider__container" dir='rtl'>
                                <div class="swiper-wrapper industry-two-slider__wrapper">
                                    {% for item in case_studies %}
                                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                                            <div class="industry-two-slider__single-item">
                                                <div class="industry-two-slider__single-item__image">
                                                    <a href="{{ item.link }}">
                                                        <img src="{{ placeholder|resize(470,300) }}" data-src="{{ Image(item.thumbnail).src|resize(470,300) }}" class="img-fluid" alt="{{ item.title }}">
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="industry-two-slider__single-item__content">
                                                    <h3 class="title">
                                                        <a href="{{ item.link }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
                                                    </h3>
                                                    <p class="subtitle">{{ item.preview.read_more('')|truncate(25) }}</p>
                                                    <a href="{{ item.link }}" class="see-more-link see-more-link--dark">SEE MORE <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">
                                 <div class="swiper-pagination-2 swiper-pagination-2"></div>
                                <button class="slider-button"><a href="https://www.jps-machinery.co.uk/case-studies/">Read More Case Studies</a></button>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 1):

Answer was ridiculously simple - wrap the second swiper inside a setTimeout function. Consider this closed!